# Constraint does not exist in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm doing a task, in which I should create a table, here's the code:

```
CREATE TABLE HumanResources.JobCandidateHistory
(
    JobCandidateID int NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    Resume xml NULL,
    Rating int NOT NULL CHECK(Rating BETWEEN 1 AND 10) DEFAULT 5,
    RejectedDate datetime NOT NULL,
    ContactID int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Person.Contact(ContactID)
);
```

So, `Rating` is checked. Next step in this task is to deactivate this check by:

```
ALTER TABLE HumanResources.JobCandidateHistory
NOCHECK CONSTRAINT CK_JobCandidateHistory_Rating;
GO

ALTER TABLE HumanResources.JobCandidateHistory
NOCHECK CONSTRAINT DF_JobCandidateHistory_Rating;
GO
```

But doing this, I get an error:

> Msg 4917, Level 16, State 0, Line 4
> Constraint 'CK_JobCandidateHistory_Rating' does not exist.

> Msg 4916, Level 16, State 0, Line 4
> Could not enable or disable the constraint. See previous errors.

> Msg 4917, Level 16, State 0, Line 7
> Constraint 'DF_JobCandidateHistory_Rating' does not exist.

> Msg 4916, Level 16, State 0, Line 7
> Could not enable or disable the constraint. See previous errors.

And I can't understand the reason, why it appears. As I understand, this constraint exists, as the column values are checked.

Comment: IF you don't explicitly provide a name for your constraints, they'll be *system-named* - and those names are tough to guess - in your case, when I re-created this table on my system, the check constraint was called `CK__JobCandid__Ratin__2DF28A67` and the default constraint `DF__JobCandid__Ratin__2EE6AEA0` - so the Best Practice is: **always** give your constraint **explicit names** so that you can refer to them later on....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give the constraints names:

```
CREATE TABLE HumanResources.JobCandidateHistory(
    JobCandidateID int NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    Resume xml NULL,
    Rating int NOT NULL DEFAULT 5,
    constraint CK_JobCandidateHistory_Rating  check (Rating BETWEEN 1 AND 10),
    RejectedDate datetime NOT NULL,
    ContactID int,
    constraint DF_JobCandidateHistory_Rating FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Person.Contact(ContactID)
);
```

The internal names are quite different from user-defined names.

Comment: Could you explain, why the DF-thing have to be in ContactID?

Comment: @Frepor . . . I don't understand the question.  This code has names for the constraints.

Comment: Well, the code for deactivation of check was given in the task, so I don't understand the reason why DF_JobCandidateHistory_Rating should be for ContactId value, if it is constraint for Rating, at least by the name

Comment: @Frepor . . . I just copied the names from your code.

Comment: @Frepor: You seem to have the impression that a constraint definition has to be always inline, after the definition of the column the constraint uses. But that's not true. Such a definition of a constraint is just a shortcut. A constraint can be defined on it's own anywhere. Note the `,` at the end of `ContactID int,`, the constraint definition that follows isn't part of that item anymore, it's an item on it's own. For some constraints the shortcut cannot even be used as there can be constraints that involve more than one column too.

Comment: I **assume** the `DF_JobCandidateHistory_Rating` should be the name of the **default constraint** on the `Rating` column - not of the foreign key constraint

Comment: @stickybit ah, now I seem to understand. So it is really doesn't matter where the constraints is? I can write both of them in the end of ```CREATE``` block, right?